# Adding background for iexplorer 7

Tags: css

I need to add a background for  in css file which is not working in iexplorer 7.

This is my code

```
      a.Previous_Poll
       {
        float: left;
        margin-top:4px;
        background-image: url('images/icn_pool_cal.png') no-repeat;
     /* background:url('images/icn_pool_cal.png')#fff none; */
        padding-left:25px !important;
        font-weight:bold !important;
        color:#003466 !important;

    }
```

Here in my code the image is not appearing in iexplorer 7.
Can anyone help me to add background-image for iexplorer 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These properties have to be separated:

```
    background-image: url('images/icn_pool_cal.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Or, the `-image` postfix has to be removed:

```
    background: url('images/icn_pool_cal.png') no-repeat;
```

See also:

- MDN: [CSS `background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background) property
- MSDN: [`background`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530722%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set repeat to the background-image;
Use background-repeat instead.

Answer (score 1):

The `background-image` property should just take the `url` of the image to use, you need to remove `no-repeat` and add that separately using the `background-repeat` property

Answer (score 1):

first of all, we cannot judge if there are style conflicts/overrides based on this code. next, check in your debugger if you have the correct url path to that image.

and lastly it's:

```
background: url('images/icn_pool_cal.png') no-repeat;
```

remove `-image`